# Call to undefined function finfo_open()

Tags: php, xampp, fileinfo

In my phpinfo, it say's that the `fileinfo` is enabled. But Im still getting the error `Call to undefined function finfo_open()`. What am I missing? Please see the image of my configuration command.

[image]
**EDIT :**
I don't have a direct access to `php.ini` because im using a shared hosting. I can request them to update it for me but im not exactly sure what other else are needed to enable other than `fileinfo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `php.ini` there should be something similar to `;extension=fileinfo.so` or `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll`. You will need to remove the `;` to *enable* these. It looks like it's trying to call a function from the .dll but cannot find it.

Comment: but the problem is, I dont have a direct access to `php.ini`. Is there a way to determine if it is enabled through `phpinfo();`?

Comment: Nope you will need to contact them and ask them to enable it as i suggested. Your `phpinfo.php` will just show where the `php.ini` is located.

Comment: I already contacted them and they said that it is already enabled. So tried to search a way to determine if there is a way to know if fileinfo is enabled through phpinfo. But almost all suggests to uncomment the `extension=fileinfo.so` (in linux).

Comment: you have confirmation they also removed the `;` from the beginning of the .dll too? They will need to reboot your Apache too after it's done to confirm changes. Maybe have them provide the contents of php.ini for your inspection