# Call to undefined function finfo_open() on cpanel 64.0.36

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to upload some photos and it shows an error called Call to undefined function `finfo_open()`. On local host it work's fine . when I upload it from  my site to live server it shows  above mentioned error. 
I'm Using Codeigniter 3

How to fix this [Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSgiB.png)

Comment: Read may be it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989465/call-to-undefined-function-finfo-open

Comment: But How I can find php.ini file.

Comment: Just a tip you are naming your controller wrong u have About_Us.php it should be About_us.php only the first letter upper case that goes for class and file name. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Read: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/phpini-file/

Comment: Edit Question with the about us controller

Comment: I tried but i cannot find the exact locaton according to the php info.

Comment: /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.ini This is the file location

Comment: Not a 100% duplicate IMO. This is a cPanel Centos Linux question where as the answer linked to focuses mostly. on Windows DLL modules. But still very similar. To make this work on cPanel you'll need to  use EasyApache to install the php-fileinfo module, for PHP72 that would be "php72-php-fileinfo". Note this will cause a reboot of your web-server.